# How to know the popup window is closed in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I am currently building chrome extension.
This extension is a kind of simple count-down timer.
It's working perfectly when I just run the native html.
But when I run it as chrome extension, I faced some issues.
When I open the popup window and keep that window open, everything is going well.
But when I close the window and reopen the window, all things are reset.
How can I detect the popup window is closed in chrome extension?
If once I can detect that event, I can use SyncStorage API to store the data what I want.

I tried to use `chrome.runtime.connect.`

But I don't have any idea how can I detect the popup window.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual approach is to write to the storage (e.g. chrome.storage.session) on every change and read the storage at the beginning of the popup's script to reuse the previous values.